# getJSON array parameter data in ashx

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, getjson

I'm having problems passing an array parameter to my .ashx handler.  Querystring parameters work fine, but I don't know how to access the array from within the ashx file.

My array is a list of strings called list.  This is how I call the getJSON method:

```
jQuery.getJSON('Handlers/AccessoryUpdateHandler.ashx?action=updateselection&a=' + a_sku, function (list) {
            //...
        });
```

In AccessoryUpdateHandler.ashx I can get the querystring parameter using `context.Request.QueryString["a"];`

But how do I get the array data?  I've looked at the Request.QueryString object but there's nothing there that looks like my array.

If there's a better way of doing this I'd also be interested to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you shouldn't rely on QueryString to pass the kind of data. I would advice you to use "POST" method instead. In either case, using the approach you are using, you wont be able to pass the data as an array. Convert the array into a string. A utility like **stringify()** can come in handy here if you dont want to convert the array into a string manually. When you extract the string from the **Request.QueryString** or **Request.Form** (in case you use post) in the handler, you can easily use **JavaScriptSerializer** to deserialize using a simple C# class that has a schema similar to your json array.

Edited: Illustration

An array like:

```
var ary = [{ "id": "1", "name": "Mark" }, { "id": "2", "name": "John"}];
```

can be converted to a string like:

```
var aryS = "[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Mark\"},{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Mark\"}]";
```

then, your QueryString can be constructed as:

```
jQuery.getJSON('Handlers/AccessoryUpdateHandler.ashx?action=updateselection&a=' + aryS, function (list) {
        //...
    });
```

when you go to your handler code, you can have a simple class to help you deserialize the data:

```
class Rec 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

with that in place, the last step to deserialize is:

```
string s = context.Request.QueryString["a"]; // HttpContext context
var jserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var ary = jserializer.Deserialize<Rec[]>(s);
```

Note you have to use Rec[] in the Deserialize function since you are deserializing into an array. **ary** will be an array of Rec with all your data from your javascript array. You need to reference System.Web.Extensions to use JavaScriptSerializer

EDIT:

I thought you were talking about an array of objects. If its just an array of **long**s, the following lines should be sufficient:

```
string s = context.Request.QueryString["a"]; // HttpContext context
var jserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var ary = jserializer.Deserialize<long[]>(s);
```

and you dont need to create a class. you would only need that if you had a array of json objects

Comment: when I do as you suggest, i get the error: 'Invalid JSON primitive: 10030113283313,10030113295513.' when i call 'serializer.Deserialize<Rec[]>(s)'.  If I use JSON.stringify() on the array in my js file, i get the error 'Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type 'AccessoryUpdateHandler+Rec'' at the same point.  But it's definitely an improvement on what I had previously!

Comment: remember that the types on the members of your class must match the types on your array objects. another thing: if some members of your json object can be null, [ like in { "id": , "name": "unknown" }, id would be undefined/null ] in such a case you might need to use a nullable member. for instance: int? Id { get; set; } if id can be null in you json object

Comment: "If I use JSON.stringify() on the array in my js file, i get the error 'Cannot convert object of type 'System.String' to type 'AccessoryUpdateHandler+Rec'' at the same point. "

Since I cant visualize your exact scenario, I would suggest you approach it stepwise. If you json object has like 10 members, you could strip all except one or two, test that serialization happens properly on the server side, and then add others stepwise. that way you would be able to know what is failing.

Comment: my array doesn't look like the one you describe, could that be the problem?  this is the string returned from stringify(): '"["10030113312013","10030113283313","10030113295513"]"'

Comment: @markpsmith I seem to have understood the complicated scenario. I edited the answer to cater for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your need for passing arrays should dictate whether you use get or post as others suggest.

Using get, the most idiomatic ways is using the same parameter multiple times. e.g.

```
Handlers/AccessoryUpdateHandler.ashx?a=1&a=2&a=55
```

In fact in most frameworks(.NET being the exception) when you get a parameter from url you get a array return(often with one item)

My suggestion is you parse context.Request.RawUrl